# How to Call System Default Email Client in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am new to blackberry so i need a code to call default email client in blackberry SDK If anybody knows share with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

[Using Webworks](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.invoke.MessageArguments.html)

[Using BB Java](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Create_new_populated_email_msg_565427_11.jsp)

Comment: @user1776252 Then check the first link.

Comment: actually i am using phonegap to build blackberry ,IOS, android, and windows phone and i need the plugin that can call the default mail in the phone for BlackBerry

Comment: I do not believe that is possible in PhoneGap (as there is no out-of-the-box API available), only WebWorks, as Mister Smith has already shared.